# Basic two-body dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to solve this easy example problem from my Physics textbook dynamics chapter. The question is "How must the weights w1 and w2 be related in order for the system to move with constant speed?" [friction in the pulley and weight of the cable can be ignored]

[image]

The solution from the textbook is:

[image]

Now, the textbook does not draw the free-body diagram of the rope and automatically reports T as the forces that act on the cart and the bucket and concludes equating their magnitude to obtain a relation between w1 and w2.
What I do not understand is how it is possible to conclude from the analysis of the rope motion equations (which is not done explicitly in the solution) that the tensions at the ends have the same magnitude given that, as you can see from the drawings, **they are expressed in two different coordinate axes**.

If I try to write the motion equation for the rope according to Newton II law what I come up with is (vector) tension@left = (vector) -tension@right which asserts that the two forces have eqaul magnitude and opposite direction and this is clearly false.

So basically the question is "how should I write motion equations for bodies that have forces acting on them expressed in different coordinate axis? (like the rope in this case)"

@Bernhard I'm not sure I understand but I'm going to write the way how I would have solved the problem so that you can correct me.

I am trying to align myself with the procedure that is reported in the book and at the same time I am trying to be more detailed:
$$Rope:\Sigma  \textbf{F} =  \textbf{F}_{RoB1}+\textbf{F}_{RoB2} = m_R\textbf{a}_R  \ (1)$$
$$Block 1: \Sigma  \textbf{F} =  \textbf{F}_{B1Ro}+\textbf{F}_{B1Ra}+\textbf{F}_{B1E} = m_{B1}\textbf{a}_{B1} \ (2)$$
$$Block 2: \Sigma  \textbf{F} =  \textbf{F}_{B2Ro}+\textbf{F}_{B2E} = m_{B2}\textbf{a}_{B2} \ (3)$$
$$constraint \ \textbf{a}_{R} = \textbf{a}_{B1} = \textbf{a}_{B2} = \textbf{a} = 0 \ (4)$$

From (1) and (4) I think I can conclude that $$ \textbf{F}_{RoB1}= -\textbf{F}_{RoB2}$$
which however basically I don't understand given that it equates two vectors expressed w.r.t. two different coordinate axes.

So it is very likely that either I'm missing something in the rationale of the whole procedure in general or special cases like these one must be treated differently. The textbook does not elaborate as I'd need about the necessity to use different coordinate axes in cases where more than one body (that move in different direction) are involved.

Comment: Have you tried writing the equations of motion for just a thin slice of the rope?

Comment: @Bernhard I've edited the post to improve the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Since the cilinder is weightless the tension of the string on body 2 (bucket) is the same as the one applied on body 1. That happenes because the string is weightless so**ΣF(string) =m×a=0**.That means that the force applied to the string by body 2 should be equal to the one applied on the string by body 1. So you have **T1=T2**. According to **Newton's 3rd law of motion** there should be an opposite and equal reaction to each of the two forces (T1, T2). That force will be applied by the string on each one of the bodies and it would have the same value on body 1 and 2. That force is the symbol T in this particular problem. **The fact that the axis of motion is different for each of the bodies does not matter**. You can study the forces applied on each body separately. If the cilinder was not weightless then the T1 would not be the same as T2. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: _[...] So you have T1=T2._

"Intuitively" I totally agree with you but still it seems to me that this reasoning comes from equation (1) and (4) and since I'm trying to align myself to the procedure reported in the book I'd like to have a more systematic explanation of this fact.

_The fact that the axis of motion is different for each of the bodies does not matter. You can study the forces applied on each body separately._

So even if these two vectors are expressed wrt different coord. ax. I'm allowed to write $\textbf{F}_{RoB1} = -\textbf{F}_{RoB2}$? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @Luca equation (1) is not written correctly. The forces that ara acting on the rope are opposite so that means that ΣF(rope) = F1 - F2 and not F1+F2. That's why in your conclusion you seem to get the minus sign. Now about the axis: To prove that the forces applied on the rope are equal you can study the rope as an individual body completely indipendent from the system of the problem. The fact that the axis change does not matter if you are trying to prove that T1=T2. They would matter if the question was: What is the force applied on the cilinder by the rope? Also for some reason I cannot read

Comment: @Luca Continuation on first comment: I cannot read the last equation you wrote on your comment. I see some strange symbols instead. Why is that? How do I fix it?